# Scanf needs more values than it should in C

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm trying to learn structs and I'm using this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct elements
{
    char name[50];
    int semester;
    char  am[15];
}student[100];

void read_struct(struct elements p[]);
int i=0;

main()
{

    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        read_struct(student);

    }
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {   printf("%d\n",i);
        printf("%s\n",student[i].name);
        printf("%s\n",student[i].am);
        printf("%d\n",student[i].semester);
    }

    system("pause");
}
void read_struct(struct elements p[])
{

    gets(student[i].name);
    gets(student[i].am);
    scanf("%d\n",&student[i].semester);
}
```

and I face the following problem:
during the second iteration when I enter the value for the variable `student[1].semester`  the program doesn't print what I've entered but it waits for me to enter another number,press enter and then it prints. I tried `fflush(stdin)` after every gets and scanf, and I got the same problem.

Comment: Indentation fixed. Now why isn't `p` used into `read_struct`, and where does `student` even exist in *any* of this code. *Post real code*.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing

```
scanf("%d\n", &student[i].semester);
```

with

```
scanf("%d", &student[i].semester);
```

---

In addition to that, `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour, so don't use it.

Comment: Then the `scanf` will leave the newline in the input buffer for the next call to `gets`, which will read an empty line.

Comment: "using fflush(stdin) invokes undefined behavior"... I'm not sure about that. The C standard only specifies what happens when `fflush` is called on an output stream. I believe the Linux distros provide value added stuff for the input streams. So I think its implementation defined, not undefined. If the wording in the standard has changed, then accept my apologies.

Comment: it worked!although why?if it was the \n the problem why didn't the fflush fix it?

Comment: @jww Check J2 of the standard, a *long* litany of undefined behavior and portability issues. Among them, inappropriate use of `fflush`: *"The stream for the `fflush` function points to an input stream or to an update stream in which the most recent operation was input". And C99 7.21.5.2 "If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong on so many levels. Instead of just adding a comment pointing them out I will show you a "more correct" way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct elements
{
    char name[50];
    int semester;
    char  am[15];
};

#define MAX_STUDENTS 2

void read_struct(struct elements *p);

int main(void)
{
    struct elements students[MAX_STUDENTS];  /* No longer global */

    for (size_t i = 0;i < MAX_STUDENTS; ++i)
        read_struct(&students[i]);  /* Pass pointer to single structure */

    for (size_t i = 0;i < MAX_STUDENTS; ++i)
    {
        printf("%ld\n", i);
        printf("%s\n", students[i].name);
        printf("%s\n", students[i].am);
        printf("%d\n", students[i].semester);
    }
}

void read_struct(struct elements *p)
{
    /* fgets is safe, in that it will not overwrite your buffer */
    fgets(p->name, sizeof(p->name), stdin);
    fgets(p->am, sizeof(p->am), stdin);
    scanf("%d", &p->semester);

    /* Skip trailing whitespace (like the newline) in the input buffer
     * left after the `scanf` call above.
     * Do it by reading one character and see if it's a newline. If it's
     * not a newline, then read next character, and so on until we get
     * the newline. It's safe because we *know* there is a newline in the
     * input buffer after the `scanf` call above.
     */
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;

    /* The `fgets function leaves the newline in the buffer so we
     * have to remove it, if it's there.
     * This is done by first checking if the last character (strlen(...) - 1)
     * is a newline, and if it is then we change that newline to the string
     * terminator character so the string is terminated there.
     */
    if (p->name[strlen(p->name) - 1] == '\n')
        p->name[strlen(p->name) - 1] = '\0';
    if (p->am[strlen(p->am) - 1] == '\n')
        p->am[strlen(p->am) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

---

The reason the trailing whitespace doesn't really work is because then the  `scanf` function will continue to read input until it sees something non-whitespace. In this case after you entered the last data, the `scanf` still wants to read and discard all whitespace, it doesn't know that the user isn't supposed to enter any more input.

You really have to manually read and skip trailing whitespace as done in my program above.

Comment: the thing chrk told,to use scanf("%d", &student[i].semester); worked..can you tell me why?

Comment: @chuckbartowski Updated my answer with an explanation on why you can't use `scanf` to skip trailing whitespace in this case.

Comment: what problems?beacause to tell you the truth,i don't really get what you're doing with the code of the read_struct function

Comment: @chuckbartowski You had the newline in the `scanf` format to tell `scanf` to read and discard the newline entered after the input. But if you don't remove it, what will happen the next time you call `gets` (and don't use that function!)? Then `gets` will see that newline and read it as an empty line.

Comment: ok man i think i understood..some of it at least..!thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for the better answer.  Mixing `fgets()` with `scanf()` is challenging.  Maybe the `fgets`/`sscanf() or strtol()` route for `&p->semester`?